Identify this horror movie featuring a demon and excorcism
I am trying to find the movie that i can't remember the name. The genre is horror and i just remember few scene, its about the man who lost some one and in the burial ceremony of that person he ruined his cross in his hand and lost his faith. After that a demon followed him and i think he made a sound like a horse, at the end a father who helped him possessed by that demon and he exorcism the father and found he called the demon in that ceremony. At the end movie said that that guy (he is a father now) is teaching exorcism in some university now.

@redddy Feel free to accept Walt's answer if it is the correct solution to your problem.

seems like @redddy has left the building

Sounds like The Rite from 2011 with Anthony Hopkins

Michael, the son of a funeral director grows indifferent to his father and joins a Seminary. On his way to the course completion, he is overwhelmed by a strong lack of faith. His religious beliefs are further jolted when he sees a young girl haplessly dying in a road accident for whom he reluctantly performs the ritual to absolve her sins. His mentor still believes in him and urges him to go to Italy to take an exorcism course hoping that he it would strengthen his faith in Christianity.

Here's the trailer:



